# cut command --complement flag equivalent in AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I am new to writing shell scripts

I am trying to write an AWK command which does exactly the below

```
cut --complement -c $IGNORE_RANGE file.txt > tmp
```

$IGNORE_RANGE can be of any value say, 1-5 or 5-10 etc

i cannot use cut since i am in AIX and AIX does not support --complement, is there any way to achieve this using AWK command

Example:

**file.txt**

```
abcdef
123456
```

**Output**

```
cut --complement -c 1-2 file.txt > tmp

cdef
3456


cut --complement -c 4-5 file.txt > tmp
abcf
1236

cut --complement -c 1-5 file.txt > tmp
f
6
```

Comment: Please provide sample input with expected output.

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and sample of expected output i your question and let us know then.

Comment: just added the required details

Comment: What's wrong with writing the complements yourself? Like `3-` for `1-2`, `-3,6-` for `4-5`?

Comment: @oguz the complement is an dynamic value, i am really not sure who to write this. if you aware can you please tell me how!?

Comment: @Rasmi, could you please do let us know in answer's section if given solutions worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. We have `range` variable of `awk` which should be in `start_of_position-end_of_position` and we could pass it as per need.

```
awk -v range="4-5" '
BEGIN{
  split(range,array,"-")
}
{
  print substr($0,1,array[1]-1) substr($0,array[2]+1)
}
' Input_file
```

OR to make it more clear in understanding wise try following:

```
awk -v range="4-5" '
BEGIN{
  split(range,array,"-")
  start=array[1]
  end=array[2]
}
{
  print substr($0,1,start-1) substr($0,end+1)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v range="4-5" '                                ##Starting awk program from here creating range variable which has range value of positions which we do not want to print in lines.
BEGIN{                                              ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  split(range,array,"-")                            ##Splitting range variable into array with delimiter of - here.
  start=array[1]                                    ##Assigning 1st element of array to start variable here.
  end=array[2]                                      ##Assigning 2nd element of array to end variable here.
}
{
  print substr($0,1,start-1) substr($0,end+1)       ##Printing sub-string of current line from 1 to till value of start-1 and then printing from end+1 which basically means will skip that range of characters which OP does not want to print.
}
'  Input_file                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: ++ better solution than mine

Comment: To make it more challenging, `cut` supports `-c -2,4-5,7-`. ;D

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `awk`:

```
awk -v st=1 -v en=2 '{print substr($0, 1, st-1) substr($0, en+1)}' file
```

```
cdef
3456
```

Or:

```
awk -v st=4 -v en=5 '{print substr($0, 1, st-1) substr($0, en+1)}' file
```

```
abcf
1236
```