# cut command --complement flag equivalent in AWK for a complex parameter

Tags: unix, awk, cut

this question is a followup on to existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356703/cut-command-complement-flag-equivalent-in-awk)

**don't mark this as duplicate as the expectation of the question is totally different**

I am trying to write an AWK command which does exactly the below

**Command 1:**

```
cut --complement -c $IGNORE_RANGE file.txt > tmp
```

**Command 2:**

```
cut --complement -d, -f$IGNORE_RANGE $report  > tmp
```

*$IGNORE_RANGE can be of any value say, 1-5,6 or 1,3,5 1,3-5 etc*

i cannot use cut since i am in AIX and AIX does not support --complement, is there any way to achieve this using AWK command

**Example for Command 1:**

file.txt

```
abcdefg
1234567
```

**Output**

```
cut --complement -c 1-5,6 file.txt > tmp
g
7


cut --complement -c 1,3,5 file.txt > tmp
bdfg
2467

cut --complement -c 1,3-5 file.txt > tmp
bfg
267
```

**Example for Command 2:**

file.txt

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7
```

**Output**

```
cut --complement -d, -f 1-5,6 file.txt > tmp
data7

cut --complement -d, -f 1,3,5 file.txt > tmp
data2,data4,data6,data7

cut --complement -d, -f 1,3-5 file.txt > tmp
data2,data6,data7
```

Comment: I believe you have 2 questions embedded into one, 1 is for positions of characters in line and one if fields, please note that characters and fields are 2 different concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution for OP's position number problem:*** Could you please try following, a generic solution based on provided samples written and tested in GNU `awk` and needed GNU `awk` to be executed. One could give ranges or individual position number separated by `,` in `awk`'s `ignore_pos` variable.

```
awk -v FS= -v ignore_pos="1-5,6" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(ignore_pos,array1,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(array1[i]~/-/){
       split(array1[i],array2,"-")
       for(j=array2[1];j<=array2[2];j++){
         ignore[j]
       }
    }
    else{
       ignore[array1[i]]
    }
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(!(i in ignore)){ val=val $i }
  }
  $0=val
  val=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution for OP's field number problem:*** When one wants to ignore fields we could use this solution then(OP's command2 examples taken here to run this). As per OP's samples `,`comma has been made as field separator for Input_file here.

```
awk -v ignore_field="1-5,6" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  num=split(ignore_pos,array1,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(array1[i]~/-/){
      split(array1[i],array2,"-")
      for(j=array2[1];j<=array2[2];j++){
        ignoreFields[j]
      }
    }
    else{
      ignoreFields[array1[i]]
    }
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    val=""
    if(!(i in ignoreFields)){  val=(val?val OFS:"")$i  }
  }
  $0=val
}
1
' Input_file
```